# looping through Map JavaScript without keys

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, key

Is there a way to loop through a JavaScript Map without knowing any of the keys? Deleting each iteration where it meets a certain criteria?

```
let map = new Map();
```

Comment: html5 map ? please  show more code..

Comment: Sure. Have you tried anything? Like, [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `forEach` over the `Map` to get every key-value pair, and if the value doesn't fulfill your condition, call `delete` with the key:

```js
const map = new Map([
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
]);
map.forEach((val, key) => {
  if (val < 3) {
    map.delete(key);
  }
});
console.log([...map.entries()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing by "Javascript Map" you mean an object, right?
If so, you can get the object properties dynamically with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

So, this is an example of iteration on an dynamic object:

```
let randomObj = {
    randomProperty: 'randomValue',
    randomProperty2: 'randomValue2',
}
const properties = Object.keys(randomObj);
properties.forEach(prop => {
    if (someCriteriaYouHave(prop))
        delete(randomObj[prop]);
});
```

If you need the property value to determine if you are going to delete it, you can get it using:

```
var propValue = randomObj[prop];
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, frankly I believe the other answer is the one. I will upvote you though